# How mysql_fetch_assoc(); with while loop iterate all elements?

Tags: php, mysql

Maybe my question seem stupid but I want to really understand not write code without understanding

If I have database and I want to use it:

```
$handle=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id");
$num=mysql_num_rows($handle);
```

then I wrote that code to iterate on the array

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($handle)){
    echo $row['username']."<br>";
}
```

My question is how while loop here iterate and stop after the elements finish, I mean where is the condition that stop while loop?

Answer (score 1):

When you run out of data, `mysql_fetch_assoc($handle)` will return `null`, so `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($handle)` will evaluate to `false`. That will stop your `while` loop.

Comment: well , so how MySQL_fetch_assoc($handle); return each time the next element or the next array ?

Comment: @SamPider I'm not entirely sure what you mean. It returns the next row, as an array.

Answer (score 0):

$handle is a mySQL resource, so X number of rows...

`$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($handle)` will return one row from the resource, or NULL when there are no more rows.

So, at some point, `$row` will evaluate as false (as there are no more rows to return) which will end the while loop.

Comment: well I understood you but what will make MySQL_fetch_assoc($handle); return each time the next row in the resource ?